# Display rendered file in gitlab (yaml)

Tags: json, gitlab, yaml, swagger

I am trying to display my Swagger API documentation in gitlab.
However, I don't want to display the source code, but the rendered file.
I have seen in another group that it is possible:
[In this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tXo6.png).
There are 2 buttons at the top to display either the code or the rendered file.
When I commit a yaml file with the swagger information in my repository, I don't have those 2 buttons and only the source code is shown. Does something special have to be activated for this?

I also tried uploading a json file, but that doesn't work either. The file was downloaded directly from Swaggerhub, both resolved and unresolved.

Comment: What's your OpenAPI file name? GitLab's OpenAPI renderer only works for [specific file names](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/#openapi-viewer).

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem.